# Stop 3d Transform clipping through parent on apple devices?

Tags: css

I have a button that has a 3d rotation applied. This works on desktop browsers, however when viewed on an iphone/ipad the button moves through the parent element and cuts it in half.

How can I prevent this happening?

Example of setup:

```css
section {
  background:grey;
  padding:20px;
  transform:translateY(10px);
}
a {
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
  background:red;
  color:#ffffff;
  padding:20px;
  transform:rotateY(45deg);
  transform-style:preserve-3d;
 }
```

```html
<section>
  <p><a>Button</a></p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving the button a little bit elevation on Z axis so it won't clip into the background:

```
transform: translateZ(200px);
```

```css
section {
  background: grey;
  padding: 20px;
  transform: translateY(10px);
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: red;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 20px;
  transform: translateZ(200px) rotateY(45deg);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <p><a>Button</a></p>
</section>
```